# Parse a multi field CSV file

Tags: csv, powershell

I have a CSV file that looks like this

```
WRK-STATION-1, Room 54
WRK-STATION-2, Room 12
WRK-STATION-3, Room 45
WRK-STATION-4, Room 11
WRK-STATION-5, Room 32
```

My current code assumes there is only 1 column in my CSV file and code looks like this:

```
$computerlist = Get-Content $COMPUTERLIST -ErrorAction Stop
foreach ($computer in $computerlist) {
    if ((Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Quiet) -eq $true) {
        # some stuff happens here
        # I would like to Output to the screen "The computer with tha name
        # WRK-STATION-1 in Room 54 has been completed"
        # Or create an output file that adds a 3rd column to my input saying
        # "COMPLETED"
    } else {
        # I would like to Output to the screen "The computer with tha name
        # WRK-STATION-1 in Room 54 has failed"
        # Or create an output file that adds a 3rd column to my input saying
        # "FAILED"
    }
```

I would like to figure out how to make it understand that there are 2 columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Import-Csv`](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh849891.aspx) instead of `Get-Content`. If the input file doesn't have a header line you can specify the column headers via the `-Header` parameter.

```
$computerlist = Import-Csv $COMPUTERLIST -Header Name,Room -ErrorAction Stop
```

That way you can use it like this:

```
foreach ($computer in $computerlist) {
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer.Name -Quiet) {
        ...
    } else {
        "Computer $($computer.Name) in $($computer.Room) has failed."
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but how do I access the 2nd field? Because foreach ($computer in $computerlist) { would be broken since there are 2 fields instead of 1

Comment: It's in the answer.  You access the first field by saying $computer.name and you access the second field by saying $computer.room.  The names "name" and "room" were arbitrary choices, declared in the -header clause of the import-csv statement.

Comment: I created a header in my CSV file and used the exact syntax you did. It uses the header as the first line of my Test-Connection. Anyway to skip it?

Comment: Please read again: *If the input file **DOESN'T** have a header line you can specify the column headers via the `-Header` parameter.*

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you need something like this?

```
  $computerlist = Get-Content $COMPUTERLIST -ErrorAction Stop
  foreach ($computerInfo in $computerlist) {
       $computer = $computerInfo -split ',' | select -First 1
       if((Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Quiet) -eq $true) {
         # some stuff happens here
         # I would like to Output to the screen "The computer with tha name WRK-STATION-1 in Room 54 has been completed"
         # Or create an output file that adds a 3rd column to my input saying "COMPLETED"
       }
       else {
         # I would like to Output to the screen "The computer with tha name WRK-STATION-1 in Room 54 has failed"
         # Or create an output file that adds a 3rd column to my input saying "FAILED"
   }
```